# Mysql data at rest encryption component file keyring

Tags: mysql-8.0, encryption

Hi I have a mysql server version 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 and I want to enable data at rest encryption component keyring file. according to this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keyring-component-installation.html I am creating a global manifest `mysqld.my` file like this:

```
{
  "components": "file://component_keyring_file"
}
```

and Im storing this into `/usr/sbin` where the mysqld is installed.

then Im creating second manifest `component_keyring_file.cnf` file like this:

```
{
  "path": "/var/lib/mysql-keyring/component_keyring_file",
  "read_only": false
}
```

and Im putting this into `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin` where the keyring component is installed.

at the end Im creating a mysqld config file into `/etc/mysql/conf.d` directory and Im writing this into it:

```
[mysqld]
default_table_encryption=ON
```

when I restart mysql process, the encryption is not working and the result of this query `SELECT * FROM performance_schema.keyring_component_status;` is empty. but when I try to create some databases in this mysql server, it says I can find master key for encryption.